# Cannot read property 'add' of undifined, Discord add role

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I decided to start making a very simple Discord bot that should give a role to a member if a different member has the same role,

For example;

> Person 1: I have the infected role

> Person 2: I dont have the infected role.

> Person 2: @Person1 blah blah blah

And now person 2 should receive the infected role, Instead that doesn't happen, And I cannot figure out a way to fix it.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
console.log("rerararararrederasd")

var infectionStarted = true; client.on("message", message => {
    if (infectionStarted) {
          try{ let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'infected');
              client.users.cache.get(message.mentions.members.first().id).roles.add(role);}catch(e){console.log(e)};
    }
});

client.login('my discord bots token ofc goes here i just removed for stackoverflow');
```

But in the console I get this issue report:

```
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.3.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.3.1/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/ec7e49f1-7b76-4ef8-9653-1982138496c7/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.3.1/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

It might be very obvious but i dont know how to solve this, If you could help me i would really appreciate it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

1. I recommend structuring your code a little better as well as destructuring your variables.
2. The issue is that `client.users.fetch()` returns a `user` which unlike a `member` has no roles. Hence why it returned `undefined`

```
client.on("message", message => {
   const infectionStarted = true
   const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'infected')
   
   // have 'member' = the mentioned member
   const member = message.mentions.members.first()

   // If there was a mention, add the role to the mentioned
   if (member) {
      // Instead of fetching the user through Discord, I add the role directly to the member object like this
      member.roles.cache.add(role)
   }   
}
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
``` 
i am now recieving this error with your solution. :(

Comment: I edited my answer. This should provide code easier to read and troubleshoot

Comment: I have just added your code and added it into the bot, Added all other necessary things aswell, But now i am having a issue with the console saying; ```TypeError: member.roles.cache.add is not a function```

Comment: Make sure your message event is seperate from your ready event and not inside it